# Electron application ipc communication between two windows

Tags: electron

There is ipc implementation for electron, it named ipcrenderer and ipcmain , they are intended for main process communication, and it does not work for communication between two windows (even passing instance of emitter).

I think, with real example will be more clear( https://github.com/linuxenko/usprited ) . I'd make toolbar and main window to be two different windows. The only problem is a communication between this two windows, ipc does not work, did not tried postmessage yet. What you can recommend for this case ? How or which eventemitter, implementation, use to communicate between windows of the electron application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your choice of IPC method will depend on the kind of data you need to share between the windows and by the way you manage the windows. For instance, if you manage your windows from the Main process, you could use the Main process as a central hub to pass around messages using Electron's 'ipc' modules. If your windows know about each other, it's probably better to exchange messages directly between them, without going through the Main process.

If you open one window from the other using Electron's [`window.open`](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.2/api/window-open/#the-windowopen-function) for example, you can then use `postMessage` on the window proxy (in the child window, use `window.opener.postMessage`) for message passing.

Of course, you could also open up a socket between the two windows or use any other form of IPC, especially if you need to pass around a lot of data. For simple messages and events `postMessage` should be fine though.

Comment: thank you @inukshuk , something like hub communication via main process looks more real , i'll try it. Please, can you explain what do you mean "socket between two windows" ? Is it possible without server ? webrtc? If so , please guide me how to implement it, it looks like very promising solution.

Comment: I meant something like opening a unix socket (if you're not supporting windows) or network sockets... one of your processes would have to play the server. I had not considered WebRTC but that might be a pretty cool idea if you want to stream video or audio... it's pretty cool what you can do with Electron.

Comment: aaah , now i understand, thank you )